# Crystal viewer inside of Visual Studios 2012 "OK" and "Cancel" buttons not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-viewer

I am trying to view a report with crystal reports viewer inside of VS2012. After I enter my parameter values I cannot go any further because my "OK" and "Cancel" buttons do nothing. My viewer is up to date, and the parameters work inside of CR2011. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage what those buttons do, go to code and write something in those events.